# C++ Why there is error when I delete pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have problem with visual studio ( i think so ). When i try compile it in Visual Studio i'm getting error (breakpoint).

```
int main()
{
    int p = 4;
    int d = 7;
    int* x = &d;
    cout << *x << endl;
    delete x;
}
```

I'm gettin error like this.
[image: ERROR]
Am i doing something wrong??? In code blocks it works. When i restart visual studio im getting this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWrRy.png

Comment: because you can only `delete` what you allocated with `new`.

Comment: So how to delete pointer in proper way?

Comment: @Kawson there is no need to delete the pointer in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delete pointer;` does not delete the pointer itself, but the data that the pointer is pointing to. In this case, that happens to be memory that's allocated on the stack when the scope of the `main()` function is entered, and is freed automatically when the scope of `main()` exits. Your program attempts to free this memory using `delete`, which is **undefined behavior** since you're calling `delete` for memory that wasn't allocated using `new`.

In your case, you should simply remove the `delete`. All memory on the stack is freed automatically at the end of `main()`: `p`, `d` and `x` (the variable holding the address, not the address it points to) were all allocated on the stack.

Comment: So, to be sure, If pointer is pointing to variable, after exit function variable is deleted then pointer points to nothing (NULL?) and I dont have to free memory because pointer is empty?

Comment: The pointer is also deleted after main().

Comment: Ok, but what in case if i create pointer int* x = new int; and then point to variable x=&y;? Should i delete pointer by delete? I see in compiler that I shouldnt (because im getting error), but doesnt it make sense when i create pointer by new then delete it?

Comment: You need to make sure all memory you allocate gets freed. In case of the stack you don't need to do anything, but in your case you need to use `delete` before changing the pointer value. `int a = 0; int* p = new int(0);...; delete p; p = &a;` Think about it this way: all memory is owned by something and if you want to write a correct program that does not cause memory leaks that something needs to make sure the memory is freed.Memory on the stack is owned by the scope and gets freed automatically without your interference,but as soon as you use `new` you take care of freeing the allocated data

Comment: @Kawson -- when a variable goes out of scope it gets **destroyed**. It doesn't get **deleted**. When you delete a pointer it gets deleted, which means that the object that it points at gets destroyed and the memory that was allocated for it is freed. That, of course, only makes sense when you created the object with `new`, which allocates memory and constructed an object in that memory. That is, these things work in pairs: construct & destroy, allocate & free, new & delete.

Comment: Okey, I found it very clear. But right now im trying these pointers. And i have new question, same subject. If i do something like that: Data* tmp = new Data; ... *head = tmp; tmp=NULL; Do i have to delete tmp anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing to an integer value on the stack. You can only delete dynamically allocated memory on the heap. You can delete it if it was created by calling `new` or `malloc()`.

```
int* ptr1 = new int;  
int* ptr2 = new int(20); 
int  intval = 20;

delete ptr1; // OK, free memory on heap
delete ptr2; // OK, free memory on heap
delete intval; // Error
```